# keypress event instead click in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events

I'm trying to implement some events using keys instead of clicks, I know that this code:

```
Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click
    My.Computer.Audio.Play("D:\VisualStudio\JuegoDIF\sonidos\sonidoPerro.wav") 
End Sub
```

is playing the sound when i click the picturebox2, but how can you do this using a key ? example:
presing the key "f5" should play the same sound as the click event

so far i tried keyDown like this:

```
   Private Sub PictureBox2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.F5) Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play("D:\VisualStudio\JuegoDIF\sonidos\sonidoPerro.wav") ' 
    End If
End Sub
```

But it's not working, and the keypress im not sure how to implement it:

```
Private Sub PictureBox2_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles 
PictureBox2.KeyPress

End Sub
```

How can I do this implementation ?

Comment: You can't. Keyboard events only make sense for controls that can receive focus. If a control can't receive focus, e.g. a `PictureBox`, then how does it make sense to process keyboard input that occurs while that control has focus? It doesn't.

Comment: After reading that I was able to find a solution, thanks for the reply @jmcilhinney

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Set the form properties to Key Preview to True

Under the Form KeyDown Event

```
 Private Sub frm_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) 
Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.F1 Then
        'Enter your Code here
    End If


    If e.KeyCode = Keys.F2 Then
         'Enter Code here
    End If
End Sub
```

This method should be the easiest one

Comment: That's fine, as far as it goes, but you would then need to allow for the fact that other controls might have focus and also have some way to distinguish which unselectable control you want your action to apply to. For instance, once a `Button` or `TextBox` gets focus, you can "unfocus" a control except by setting `ActiveControl` to `Nothing` in code, so how do you then identify that you're doing something related to `PictureBox2`?

Comment: If I got ImJP correctly, he wanna fire an event using F5 Key so I suppose he can predefine the Event in a sub and fire it using this method. The best solution really depends on what he really wants. We both don't really know how many pictures are in the form or he may use different for different pictures to fire the event for different pictures. It may not be the perfect answer but this is something @ImJP can explore.

Comment: @YatFeiLeong yeah actually i'm going to give it a try and see the behaviour, Thanks a lot really, this is a great starting point to solve the problem out